# Bokeh embeded in Tornado: 'unicode' does not have the buffer interface

Tags: python, unicode, tornado, bokeh

I'm trying to embed a bokeh server in tornado and use bokeh authentication features. However, the function check_session_id_signature, under bokeh.util.session_id.py module calls python standard library function hmac without enconding the second parameter as utf-8. The hmac function requires both parameters to have the same format, and as a result, tornado throws the following error:

TypeError: 'unicode' does not have the buffer interface

To reproduce the issue, i run the code and paste http://localhost:5006/bkapp/?bokeh-session-id=..., where the session id comes from the print executed after generating session id.

I'm well aware the user/password authentication needs to be done outside the bokeh server, but this is merely a proof of concept.

Do you know any possible solutions for the issue described above?

The code i'm using is the following:

```
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
import pandas as pd
import yaml

from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.web import RequestHandler

 from bokeh.application import Application
 from bokeh.application.handlers import FunctionHandler
 from bokeh.embed import autoload_server
 from bokeh.layouts import column
 from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Slider
 from bokeh.plotting import figure
 from bokeh.server.server import Server
 from bokeh.themes import Theme
 from bokeh.util.session_id import generate_session_id

 env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('templates'))


class IndexHandler(RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        template = env.get_template('embed.html')
        script = autoload_server(url="http://localhost:5006/?bokeh-session-id={}".format(id))
        self.write(template.render(script=script, template="Tornado"))


    def modify_doc(doc):
        data_url = "http://www.neracoos.org/erddap/tabledap/B01_sbe37_all.csvp?time,temperature&depth=1&temperature_qc=0&time>=2016-02-15&time<=2017-03-22"
        df = pd.read_csv(data_url, parse_dates=True, index_col=0)
        df = df.rename(columns={'temperature (celsius)': 'temperature'})
        df.index.name = 'time'

        source = ColumnDataSource(data=df)

        plot = figure(x_axis_type='datetime', y_range=(0, 25), 
        y_axis_label='Temperature (Celsius)',
              title="Sea Surface Temperature at 43.18, -70.43")
        plot.line('time', 'temperature', source=source)

    def callback(attr, old, new):
        if new == 0:
            data = df
        else:
            data = df.rolling('{0}D'.format(new)).mean()
            source.data = ColumnDataSource(data=data).data

    slider = Slider(start=0, end=30, value=0, step=1, title="Smoothing by N Days")
    slider.on_change('value', callback)

    doc.add_root(column(slider, plot))

bokeh_app = Application(FunctionHandler(modify_doc))

io_loop = IOLoop.current()

id = generate_session_id('cQcDfBwdwjpsPxGIth2ynud2mQcbXLQH8LQ4251OJca4', signed=True)

print "/bkapp/?bokeh-session-id={}".format(id)

server = Server({"/bkapp": bokeh_app}, io_loop=io_loop, extra_patterns=[('/', IndexHandler)],secret_key='cQcDfBwdwjpsPxGIth2ynud2mQcbXLQH8LQ4251OJca4', sign_sessions=True,generate_session_ids=False)
server.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from bokeh.util.browser import view

    print('Opening Tornado app with embedded Bokeh application on http://localhost:5006/')

    io_loop.add_callback(server.show, "/")
    io_loop.start()
```

Comment: The data that is fed into HMAC needs to be binary, not a UTF-8 string. Use `.encode()` at the appropriate place

Comment: I cannot go and change the bokeh library, i expect another workaround

Comment: Maybe you can get the client to POST it's data as `application/octet-stream` ?